# Use logger name if MDC key missing

Tags: logback, mdc

I am using logback with a third party package which sets an identifier in the MDC when its code is running.  The rest of the time, this identifier is not set.  So if I use a `PatternLayout` of `[%X{id}] %m%n`, then I see messages like

```
[Foo] Foo running
[Bar] Bar running
```

for messages related to the package.  However, the rest of my log statements look like

```
[] Thing happened
```

The `%X{id}` is useful information when it exists, but I would like the logger name to be used when it is not.  I tried

```
[%X{id:-%logger{20}}]
```

and

```
[%X{id:-logger{20}}]
```

but neither used the logger name as a default value.

I could write a custom layout that sets id to the logger name if it is not set, forwards to the layout and then clears field.  Is there a simpler way to do this?